# Python script (PyMySQL) does not connect to database on localhost

Tags: python, mysql

When I am using PHP I can connect to the phpMyAdmin at the localhost simply by writing the following lines in my php script:

```
<?php

$dbServername = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'Work';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

?>
```

*(The directory of this script is `/Users/User/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/index.php`)*

Before running the above lines, I have firstly activated `XAMPP` and I have enabled port `localhost:8080`. `phpMyAdmin` is located at `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/`. **This connects perfectly fine to the database.**

Now, in Python I have downloaded `PyMySQL` and I have written the following lines to do the same simple task:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='Work')
```

*(The directory of this script is `/Users/User/PycharmProjects/First/Main.py`)*

However, when I try to run this (after I have firstly activated `XAMPP` and I have enabled port `localhost:8080`) I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 920, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/GCP-OCR/Main.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='Work')
  File "/Users/User/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/User/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 699, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/User/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 967, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")
```

**How can I fix this error and finally connect my Python script to the MySQL database?**

Also, keep in mind that even if I replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` I am getting exactly the same error. Moreover, if I replace `localhost` with `localhost:3306` then I am an error too (`socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`).

Comment: mysql runs on port 3306 by default. did you try `$dbServername = 'localhost:3306';`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I had the impression that the default port for python is `127.0.0.1` since also this is where I run some basic web development stuff with `Flask`. However, I tried what you said and I am still getting an error as I show above at the edited post. (By the way, `$dbServername = 'localhost:3306';` in your comment is PHP not Python)

Comment: "127.0.0.1" is an IP address, not a port. And FWIW phpmyadmin is not "a MySQL database", it's a web frontend client for MySQL.

Comment: Run " mysqladmin variables | grep socket " to get where the socket is located, and try setting up a connection like so:

pymysql.connect(db='base', user='root', passwd='pwd', unix_socket="/tmp/mysql.sock")
Run "mysqladmin variables | grep port" and verify that the port is 3306. If not, you can set the port manually like so:

pymysql.connect(db='base', user='root', passwd='pwd', host='localhost', port=XXXX)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @brunodesthuilliers. I did not say this anywhere about `phpmyadmin` but yes `127.0.0.1` is an IP address, not a port. However, to be honest, I would prefer a solution to my problem than these remarks...

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Md.MahmudHasan. I need a way more clear and analytical explanation of what you are writing to understand it. To start with, where to run `mysqladmin variables | grep socket`?

Comment: You can experiment adding bind_address parameter to connect() - when the client has multiple network interfaces, specify the interface from which to connect to the host. Argument can be a hostname or an IP address. Alos check mysqld log - it can be related to 'root' user grants.

Comment: @Poete_Maudit In one comment, you tell that you don't want remarks which extend your knowledge, in the next one you ask questions for extending your knowledge. What now?

Comment: @glglgl you seem to be too intelligent to ask these bad questions. I said "However, to be honest, I would prefer a solution to my problem than these remarks...". What do you understand really from this? Let me paraphrase it a bit: "I appreciate these general remarks (which extend my knowledge) but I prefer an answer (which extends my knowledge) to my specific question"...

Comment: I am also getting the same problem, please post the answer if you found

Answer (score 0):

PyMySQL accepts port as an independent parameter. Try this out:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='Work')
```

Refer this link  : [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py)

Answer (score 0):

Just I followed the steps given in below URL, they give sample code to connect from MySQLdb plugin and PyMySQL plugin.

For me MySQLdb gives output and PyMySQL gives the connection error as like you get.

https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connecting-to-mysql-using-python